# Dataset using iterative hilt in windowing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-itertools

This is my true code, but I haven't true output

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
def moving_window(x, length, step=1):
    streams = it.tee(x, length)
    return zip(*[it.islice(stream, i, None, step+2) for stream, i in zip( streams,it.count(step=step))])
x_=list(moving_window(x,6))

for i in range(len(x_)):
    globals()['a'+str(i)] = list(x_[i])
    print(x_[i])

def mean(dataset):
    return sum(dataset) / len(dataset)
for i in range(len(x_)):
    globals()['a'+str(i)] = list(x_[i])
    a=mean(x_[i])
    print(a)
```

This output now is:

```
   3.5
   6.5
```

But I want a code with the following output:

```
| A header | Another header |


| a1   | 3.5           |

| a2   | 6.5           |
```

These rows and columns continue

Comment: NOt a `machine-learning` or `jupyter-notebook` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting this:

```
dct = {}
for i in range(len(x_)):
    globals()['a'+str(i)] = list(x_[i])
    a=mean(x_[i])
    dct[f'a{i+1}'] = a
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
>>> dct
{'a1': 3.5, 'a2': 6.5}
```

**Update:**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dct.items(), columns=['A header', 'Another header'])
>>> df
    A header    Another header
0         a1    3.5
1         a2    6.5
```

Comment: @sanaz, edited answer